# Equivalent temporel de "ailleurs"

Tags: vocabulaire, adverbes

J'ai réalisé l'élégance et la flexibilité du mot *ailleurs*. Il peut désigner un lieu précis :

> Tu préfères qu'on se retrouve au café, ou *ailleurs* ?

mais est également utilisé dans des sens plus abstraits :

> Où qu'il aille, il se sentait *ailleurs*.
>
> L'herbe est plus verte ici que partout *ailleurs*.
>
> Ils partaient explorer sous l'emprise d'un désir d'*ailleurs*.

Quel serait l'équivalent temporel pour ce mot ?

Pour des usages concrets j'utilise *à un autre moment*, *à une autre époque*... mais ces expressions me paraissent beaucoup plus spécifiques.

Comment: « Plus tard » ne te conviens pas ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez *Plus tard* indique que c'est forcément après, alors qu'un mot générique devrait pouvoir désigner un moment avant ou après.

Comment: Il n'y a pas de mot, personnellement j'utilise *à un autre moment* dans quasiment tous les cas, ça correspond parfaitement (de la même manière que *"ailleurs"* = *"à un autre endroit"*)

Comment: Les expressions avec "moment" en général me semblent assez peu génériques car limitées à des périodes en-dessous de (disons) un mois. Je trouverais étrange de dire, par exemple, "Les standards modernes de beauté sont différents de ceux qu'on a pu avoir à d'autres moments".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il me semble qu'il n'y ait pas un équivalent, mais plusieurs et ils dépendent du point dans le temps où on place l'action ou l'état ; dans la liste ci-dessous sont inclus ces termes qui semblent apporter une certaine spécificité comme celle de « période définie » que l'on peut associer au terme « à une autre époque » ou celle de « période relativement proche » que confère le terme « à courte échéance ».

**futur**

- en des temps à venir, à l'avenir, dans le futur, à un autre moment, plus tard, dans quelques temps, à longue échéance, à courte échéance, dans un futur proche, dans un futur lointain, à une autre époque, jamais, …

**passé**

- jadis, autrefois, en d'autres temps, par le passé, en des temps reculés, au bon vieux temps (plusieurs connotations, selon le contexte), en un autre temps, en des temps immémoriaux, à une autre époque, jamais …

**pas bien défini**

- en un autre temps

*Quelques uns des termes listés commutent avec « ailleurs » dans les  phrases fournies ; il peut y en avoir d'autres ; c'est un exercice de voir s'ils sont utilisables.*

- Tu préfères qu'on se retrouve demain, ou **dans quelques temps** ?
- Tu préfères qu'on se retrouve demain, ou **plus tard** ?
- Où qu'il aille, il se sentait **en un autre temps**.
- L'herbe est plus verte en ces jours de convalescence que **jamais** je ne l'ai vue.
- L'herbe est plus verte  que **jamais** tu ne la verras.
- Ils partaient explorer sous l'emprise d'un désir du **temps jadis**.

Comment: "En un autre temps" est intéressant. Cela me fait pense que l'expression (lue en science-fiction) "Another time, another place" pourrait être traduite par "Ailleurs, en un autre temps". Est-ce que vous considéreriez cela idiomatique ou un peu maladroit ?

Comment: Quoi qu'il en soit l'idée que les mots abstraits équivalents à "ailleurs" soient séparés entre passé et futur est intéressante et m'avait échappé ; on parle bien de "désir d'avenir" ou de "désir d'autrefois". Même si la conclusion me frustre quelque peu je pense que cette réponse est la plus proche de ce que je demandais.

Comment: @Jhyn Tout dépend du contexte et de ce que l'on veut communiquer mais il est difficile de critiquer ; s'il s'agit des aspirations rêveuses de quelqu'un c'est concevable : on peut ne penser qu'à des endroits réels du pays, de la planète (Il aurait voulu se trouver ailleurs, en un autre temps.). S'il s'agit de science fiction, c'est encore une possibilité qui me semble concevable mais on ne communique pas les mêmes connotations qu'avec « en un autre monde, en un autre temps »; néanmoins cette dernière possibilité est (champ 1)

Comment: @Jhyn encore applicable à la situation du rêveur (connotations différentes, avec peut être en plus un contexte de science fiction). (fin)

Answer (score 0):

En prenant en compte le fait que vous cherchez un mot générique pouvant désigner un moment avant ou après, vous pouvez utiliser:

- au moment opportun

> Il est fondamental que des solutions à ce problème
>   soient examinées **au moment opportun**.
>
> Je suis désolé mais je n'ai pas le temps en ce moment, nous nous retrouverons pour prendre un café **au moment opportun**.

*Voir également:  à pic, au bon moment, au moment souhaité, au moment voulu.*

Comment: 'Opportun' est positif alors que 'ailleurs' est neutre.

Answer (score 0):

> Pour des usages concrets j'utilise à un autre moment, à une autre époque... mais ces expressions me paraissent beaucoup plus spécifiques.

- 'à une autre époque' est abstrait, passé, distant -- par ex. 'c'est ainsi que les choses se seraient passées à une autre époque' ;
- 'à un autre moment' est très polyvalent : passé ou avenir, proche ou distant.

Answer (score 0):

Given the translation to English is *somewhere/anywhere else* (i.e. *some/any other place*), the temporal equivalent would be *some/any other time*, so **à un/tout autre moment** seems to fit.